# Precision and F-score are ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples. Use `zero_division` parameter to control this behavior

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I am running a logistic regression, but I am obtaining an f1-score of 0.0. I think this has to do with zero-division error but I am unable to fix it

```
data4=data[['Age','BusinessTravel_Travel_Frequently','DistanceFromHome','Education','EnvironmentSatisfaction','Gender_Male','JobInvolvement','YearsWithCurrManager','MaritalStatus_Married','JobSatisfaction','NumCompaniesWorked','TotalWorkingYears','TrainingTimesLastYear','YearsAtCompany','Performance_dummy']]

X1=data4[['Age','BusinessTravel_Travel_Frequently','DistanceFromHome','Education','EnvironmentSatisfaction','Gender_Male','JobInvolvement','YearsWithCurrManager','MaritalStatus_Married','JobSatisfaction','NumCompaniesWorked','TotalWorkingYears','TrainingTimesLastYear','YearsAtCompany']]

y1=data4.Performance_dummy
# split X and y into training and testing sets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train1,X_test1,y_train1,y_test1=train_test_split(X1,y1,test_size=0.5,random_state=0,stratify=y1)

# import the class
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

# instantiate the model (using the default parameters)
logreg1 = LogisticRegression(max_iter=1000)

# fit the model with data
logreg1.fit(X_train1,y_train1)

#
y_pred1=logreg1.predict(X_test1)
print('Accuracy of logistic regression classifier on test set: {:.2f}'.format(logreg1.score(X_test1, y_test1)))
```

I got the following output

```
Accuracy of logistic regression classifier on test set: 0.85
```

I ran the confusion matrix code as shown below

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
confusion_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test1, y_pred1)
print("Confusion Matrix:\n",confusion_matrix)
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
print("Classification Report:\n",classification_report(y_test1, y_pred1,zero_division=1))
```

output for above code

```
Confusion Matrix:
 [[622   0]
 [113   0]]
Classification Report:
               precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.85      1.00      0.92       622
           1       1.00      0.00      0.00       113

    accuracy                           0.85       735
   macro avg       0.92      0.50      0.46       735
weighted avg       0.87      0.85      0.78       735
```

I also ran this code to understand the ratio of outcomes in my test data, and got the following output, but I am not sure how to fix this zero division error

```
from collections import Counter
print(Counter(y_train1))
print(Counter(y_test1))
```

output

```
Counter({0: 622, 1: 113})
Counter({0: 622, 1: 113})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `f1-score` is ill-defined as your model is only predicting one class (`0`).

You could use `class_weight="balanced"` on your `LogisticRegression` to penalize sample that are under represented.

If this not work it might be wise to augment the train set size or use a more advanced model.